# jquery: how to get different content with different button click?

Tags: jquery

i'm new to jquery, and i'm trying to implement multiple buttons to the same modal (bootstrap), so that it will display relevant content with different button click.

I have the following code:

```
$(".demo").click(function (){

  var demo2title = "title 2";
  var demo1title = "title 1";

  var demoID = $(this).attr("id");
  var demoTitle = demoID.concat("title");
  $(".title").html(demoTitle);
});
```

`demoTitle` is suppose to concatenate the clicked element and merge it with `"title"`, to create e.g.: demo2 + title = demo2title. 
and then `.html(demoTitle)` is suppose to display the var object (`demo2title`). but it just displays "demo2title" as the title, instead of "title 2"...

What can I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`demo1title` and `demo2title` are variables, whereas the value of `demoTitle` is a *string*. So `.html(demoTitle)` is going to set the HTML to the content of its string value, not the value of a *variable with the same name as the string*.

The only way to really access an identifier by string is via `[]` with properties. For example:

```
var titlesByID = {
  demo1: 'title 1',
  demo2: 'title 2'
};

$(".demo").click(function (){    
  var demoID = $(this).attr("id");
  var demoTitle = titlesByID[demoID];
  $(".title").html(demoTitle);
});
```